# What value does the sum of the square of the reciprocals of the prime counting function converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Using my only mathematical tool Wolfram Alpha, I noticed that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi(x)}$ seems to diverge. Naturally, the entered the following sum and, just like the zeta function, saw that it converges when each term is squared! The partial sums from [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201/%28pi%28x%29%29%5E2%20from%202%20to%20infinity) suggest that it converges to a number greater than $e$ and would like to know if a closed form is known.

$$\sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac{1}{{\pi(x)}^2} = ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a more elementary way to do it but I am going to risk total overkill by using (part of) the Prime Number Theorem.  There is a constant $c>0$, in fact any $c<1$ will do, such that
$$\pi(x)>\frac{cx}{\log x}$$
for all sufficiently large $x$.  Therefore
$$\frac{1}{\pi(n)^2}<\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{(\log n)^2}{n^2}\ ,$$
for all large $n$, and the series converges by comparison with 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2-\varepsilon}}\ .$$

In fact a similar argument will show that for any $a>1$, the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\pi(n)^a}$$
converges.  For $a=1$, the first series you looked at, it does indeed diverge because the terms include all of the numbers
$$\frac{1}{1}\,,\ \frac{1}{2}\,,\ \frac{1}{3}\,,\ldots\ ,$$
with many of them repeated.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there's a closed form, but you might notice that $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\pi(n)^2} = -2 + \sum_{j=2}^\infty \left( \dfrac{1}{(j-1)^2} - \dfrac{1}{j^2} \right) p_j$$
where $p_j$ is the $j$'th prime.